# How can I let an iOS Teams App user use my Bot without inform the MicrosoftAppId?

Tags: ios, botframework, microsoft-teams

I want Teams users to use my Bot.
But I don't want to inform the MicrosoftAppId of the Bot for the users.

According to this site : https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-teams/botsadd

I tried the way 1(select Add to Microsoft Teams) and the way 3(Get or create a deeplink)

(I skipped the way 2 since it needs information about MicrosoftAppId)

Those ways worked for users using Teams in Windows PC.
But they never worked for users using Teams in iOS Moblie.

So, how can I solve the problem?
Is there any other way to let the users use my Bot without inform the MicrosoftAppId?

Comment: What is your concern about sharing the app id,  There's not much anyone can do with that piece of information alone.

Comment: The AppId is not secret, as @JasonSowers says - what's the concern?

Comment: Thanks for quick responses.
Yes. I have a concern.
AppId is "difficult" for users I assumed.

The users are not familiar to IT.
They may reject such a long confusing string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implicit registration of a bot from mobile device is not supported yet. In order to discover a bot, user need to invoke the bot at least once from desktop client/web.

Alternatively, you could [sideload your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/apps/apps-sideload) in perticular team by creating an app manifest file. Sideloaded bots can be discovered by all the members by bot name.